# Capturing HTTPS traffic of application

Tags: proxy, ssl, certificate, reverse-proxy, fiddler

I want to use Charles/Fiddler to capture HTTPS traffic from application.

After installing trusted root certificate I've noticed that not every application will accept it. For example, I can intercept all requests made by Chrome, but on Firefox I need to add trusted certificate.

When capturing traffic for Java application, certificate need to be added to JVM TrustStore, and in case of using Python script we need to add line of code that use exported certificate.

How can I analyze requests made by some software that support proxy (so reverse proxy can be easily used), but after running it I cannot get plaintext as it needs trusted certificate?

Comment: There is no general mechanism. Every application is free to implement certificate verification however it wishes; some will specifically use a *pinned* certificate so they don't even care about your trust chain but only the specific certificate they accept. The OS certificate store only applies to the programs that actually use it.

Comment: Thank you so much for response! It clears a lot for me.
Is it possible to capture requests from application that not accept generated certificate?

Comment: Not with a proxy, no. If there is absolutely no way to tell it to accept your certificate, all you can do is attach a debugger directly to the process and read the application's memory. This is significantly more difficult, of course. (Another possibility, if the application or server uses a weak implementation, is to attack the encryption or protocol directly. YMMV.)